# SQLite Insert into where error

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to use the following code

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO players (wins) VALUES (?) WHERE username = ?", (wins[3], players))
```

and am getting the following error

```
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO players (wins) VALUES (?) WHERE username = ?", (wins[3], players))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

My table has two columns, username and wins. Wins[3] is the list value that stores the win integer, and players is the username.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `WHERE` part in an `INSERT` statement; `INSERT` only *adds* a new row, so there is nothing to limit what existing rows the statement applies to here.

You want to use an `UPDATE` instead:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE players SET wins=? WHERE username = ?", (wins[3], players))
```

Comment: Okay - how would I put the wins into a table where the username already exists. Use update?

Comment: @Wilson: Or possibly an [`ON CONFLICT UPDATE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) clause on your `INSERT`. If you give us your (a stripped-down version of) your actual schema and code, it will make answering you easier. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details.